# JavaFx ComboBox is not getting correct value on first click

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a Combo Box from java FXML, i have populated it with my array list.  When i click on the combo box for the frist time it returns null but then when i click on it again it would return the correct value.  What should really happen is that when i click on the combo box for the first time it should return the correct value the first click not the second click.

What i had :

```
package main.controller.manageAccounts;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import main.model.MangeAccounts.ManageAccountsModel;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ManageAccountsController implements Initializable {
    public ManageAccountsModel manageAccountsModel = new ManageAccountsModel();

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> customerDropDownList;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername, txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtPassword, txtSecretQuestion, txtSecretQuestionAnswer;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            populateCustomerdropDownList();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (manageAccountsModel.isDbConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Database connection established");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database connection not established");
        }
    }

    public void populateCustomerdropDownList() throws SQLException {
        customerDropDownList.setItems(manageAccountsModel.getEmployeeId());
    }

    public void setFields(MouseEvent mouseEvent) throws SQLException {
        String getEmployeeId = customerDropDownList.getValue();
        int employeeId = Integer.parseInt(getEmployeeId);
        txtUsername.setText(manageAccountsModel.getUserName(employeeId));
        txtFirstName.setText(manageAccountsModel.getFirstName(employeeId));
        txtLastName.setText(manageAccountsModel.getLastName(employeeId));
        txtPassword.setText(manageAccountsModel.getPassword(employeeId));
        txtSecretQuestion.setText(manageAccountsModel.getSecretQuestion(employeeId));
        txtSecretQuestionAnswer.setText(manageAccountsModel.getSecretQuestionAnswer(employeeId));
        System.out.println(employeeId);
    }
}
```

What i have tried :

```
    public void populateCustomerdropDownList() throws SQLException {
        customerDropDownList.setItems(manageAccountsModel.getEmployeeId());
    }

    public void setFields(MouseEvent mouseEvent) throws SQLException {
        customerDropDownList.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (event) -> {
            String getEmployeeId = customerDropDownList.getValue();
            int employeeId = Integer.parseInt(getEmployeeId);
            try {
                txtUsername.setText(manageAccountsModel.getUserName(employeeId));
                txtFirstName.setText(manageAccountsModel.getFirstName(employeeId));
                txtLastName.setText(manageAccountsModel.getLastName(employeeId));
                txtPassword.setText(manageAccountsModel.getPassword(employeeId));
                txtSecretQuestion.setText(manageAccountsModel.getSecretQuestion(employeeId));
                txtSecretQuestionAnswer.setText(manageAccountsModel.getSecretQuestionAnswer(employeeId));
                System.out.println(employeeId);
            } catch (SQLException  e) {
                System.out.println("Work?");
            }
        });
    }
```

FXML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.controller.manageAccounts.ManageAccountsController">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <children>
            <ComboBox fx:id="customerDropDownList" onMouseClicked="#setFields" prefWidth="150.0" translateY="80.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Select Customer" translateY="60.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Change Username" translateY="-60.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtFirstName" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Change First Name" translateY="-25.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtLastName" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Change Last Name" translateY="10.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtPassword" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Change Password" translateY="45.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtSecretQuestion" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Change Secret Question" translateY="80.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtSecretQuestionAnswer" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Change Secret Answer Question" translateY="115.0" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" translateY="-30.0" StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" />
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Manage User Accounts" translateY="20.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image: First Selection Returns Null]

[image: Click on it again then it shows values based]

Comment: Use an `onAction` handler, not whatever low-level mouse event you are using. (Apart from anything, you presumably want this to work if the user navigates with the keyboard.) If that doesn't work, create and post a [mre].

Comment: based on click should get id

Comment: Yes, we know that. Did you try what I said?

Comment: @James_D is right.  The correct Event is OnAction for a ComboBox drop-down item selection.  I'm going to guess that your first mouse click event might be the one that opens the pop-up of the ComboBox.  Also, it's not clear why you are passing the event to `setFields()` since it doesn't use it.  Also, also, I'm gonna bet that your `ManageAccountsModel` is accessing a database on the FXAT - which is a bad thing too.

Comment: Also, you might be better off putting a ChangeListener on the ComboBox's `value` property.

Comment: @DaveB is also right LOL. A change listener would be the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Fix to make it so so that the first click would get the value selected instead of returning null and making user have to click on the combo box again is :

Change in FXML file `onMouseClicked="#setFields"` to `onAction="#setFields"` as mentioned by James and change `public void setFields(MouseEvent mouseEvent)` to  `public void setFields(ActionEvent event)`

Doing this once the user clicks on the drop down the value will be taken immediately.

Updated Code

```
    public void setFields(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        String getEmployeeId = customerDropDownList.getValue();
        int employeeId = Integer.parseInt(getEmployeeId);
        try {
            txtUsername.setText(manageAccountsModel.getUserName(employeeId));
            txtFirstName.setText(manageAccountsModel.getFirstName(employeeId));
            txtLastName.setText(manageAccountsModel.getLastName(employeeId));
            txtPassword.setText(manageAccountsModel.getPassword(employeeId));
            txtSecretQuestion.setText(manageAccountsModel.getSecretQuestion(employeeId));
            txtSecretQuestionAnswer.setText(manageAccountsModel.getSecretQuestionAnswer(employeeId));
            System.out.println(employeeId);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Work?");
        }
    }
```